# Is it possible to iterate over type values in Typescript and generate a new type based on them?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, typing

I am trying to create a type definition for my redux `ACTION_HANDLERS` and I need to get the types for all actions. I have an action union type which holds the action type and the payload type but I can't find any examples on how to iterate over and extract them.

I am not sure it is possible to do yet, but maybe someone can help find a solution.

```js
import generateReducer from '@/utils/generateReducer';
import action, { ActionsUnion } from '@/utils/action';

const initialState = {};

const ADD = '[elements] ADD';
const REFRESH = '[elements] REFRESH';

export const ActionCreators = {
  add: action<typeof ADD, { elementIds: string[] }>(ADD),
  refresh: action(REFRESH)
};

// This is what I'm trying to create types for
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [ADD]: (state, { payload }) => ({ ...state, ...payload }),
};

export default generateReducer(ACTION_HANDLERS, initialState);
```

```js
// Here are some useful types to explain everything better
const ActionCreators: {
    add: ActionWithPayloadFn<"[elements] ADD", { elementIds: string[]; }>;
    refresh: ActionFn<"[elements] REFRESH">;
}

// ActionCreators with no keys
type ActionsUnion = ActionWithPayload<"[elements] ADD", { elementIds: string[]; }> | Action<"[elements] REFRESH">

// How can I use the 'ActionsUnion' type above to generate something like:
type ActionHandlers = {
    "[elements] ADD": (state: any, ActionWithPayload<"[elements] ADD", { elementIds: string[] }>) => any,
    "[elements] refresh": (state: any, Action<"[elements] refresh">) => any
}

// Here is some pseudo-code:
type ActionHandlers<StateType, ActionsUnion> = {
    const resultType = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < ActionsUnion.length; i++) {
      resultType[ActionsUnion[i].type] = (state: StateType, action: ActionsUnion[i]) => StateType
    }

    return resultType;
}

// So I would be able to use it like so:
const ACTION_HANDLERS: ActionHandlers<MyStateType, ActionsUnion> = {...}
```

If there is a better approach of typing redux store and logics I'd love to hear that too.

Comment: I don't use redux so I don't have the `ActionsUnion` definition, but I'd suggest using a generic constraint, like `type actionHandlers<S, A extends any[]> = ...` so that the compiler knows that `A` is an array type.  Or maybe even `type actionHandlers<S, A extends ActionUnion<any>> = ...`.

Comment: @jcalz I tried your approach and couldn't make it work. I need something more like: `type ActionHandlersType<S, A> = { [K in keyof A]: (state: S, action: ActionWithPayload<K, A[K]>) => S };`